# pygame - Getting name of pressed key

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to get the key name for the keys pressed inside a pygame window.

I have this code:

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    while True:
         SizeWindow = (1000,600)
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SizeWindow)
         pygame.display.flip()
         for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 keyname = pygame.key.name(event.key)
                 print keyname
```

which works perfectly for letters and numbers but each time I press one of the function keys, the code returns a letter instead of the name of the fuction key. For example, when I press 'f3' I receive 'b' (instead of 'f3').

I don't know what's wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When posting debugging question, make sure to create a [mcve]. Your code is minimal but it's not verifiable. People who'll try the code you've provided will not be able to test and verify the problem/error you're experiencing. Write something like [this](https://hastebin.com/vimoboqira.cs) instead.

Comment: When I tried the code I provided in the comment above I couldn't replicate the problem. The program printed `f3` when I pressed F3, both for python 2.7 and python 3.5.

Comment: And the reason why people who try the code you've provided will not be able to test and verify it is because the program will exit immediately and pygame needs a screen in order to receive any inputs at all. So before posting a question, make sure to copy the code you've provided in the question and try it out for yourself. Make sure it works and produces the same problem/error.

Comment: I added the part of the code where I initialize the pygame screen but I'm still experiencing the same problem..

Comment: Okay, and the code you've provided is the exact code your using to test this? No more, no less? In that case it seems to be something odd. What operating system are you using? And what pygame version are you using?

Comment: Found the problem! Thanks!

Comment: If you found the problem it might be good to write what it was, in case other people encounter the same problem.